# Get 2d array from API Post request in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, postman

I can't get the 2D array of API post request. Can't make the logic to get multiple arrays from JSON format API in php.
The structure of JSON API request is:

```
"abc": [{"id": 123, "days": [{"a": 11, "b": 11},{"a":22, "b":22}]} , {"id": 456, "days": [{"a": 33, "b": 33},{"a":44, "b":44}]}
```

I'm trying this logic of 2d array to get values of ID and A, B which I know is not correct formatted.

```
foreach ($request->abc as $ids => $id) {
    foreach ($id => array_combine($a, $b)) {
        $value .= $this->helper($id, $a, $b);
    }
}
```

I am already retreiving the single array from API throught this loop successfully:

```
// single array structure from post request "abc": {"single_array_val":[11,12,13,14,15]}
foreach ($request->abc as $single_arrays => $single_array) {
  $value .= $this->helper($single_arrays, $single_array);
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are properties of the objects inside the `days` array, so you should loop over the latter.

Comment: But I can't figure out the way of calling these properties of days in PHP.

Comment: If you are looping over `abc`, that gives you access to those objects contained in that array. So now you need to access the `days` property of each object ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through this loop I called the objects of "abc":

```
foreach ($request->abc as $abc) {
    $value .= $this->helper($abc['id'], $abc['days']);
}
```

Then I called the helper function where I developed a loop for 'days' object:

```
public function helper($id, $days)
{
    $days_value = "";
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $days_value .= $this->helper2($day['a'], $day['b']);
    }
    return echo 'the id is: '. $id .' and this have days' . $days_value; 
}
```

And here is the helper2 function where I decoded the values of a and b by sending them as parameters:

```
public function helper2($a, $b)
{
    return 'this is a:' . $a . ', this is b:' . $b;
}
```

Now I could easily pass the values of a and b to the helper2 function as parameters.
Hope anyone may find it helpful.

Comment: It is unlikely that future readers will find this page helpful.  No one knows what the `helper2()` method does.  Your input is JSON, but you never show where you are decoding it.  I don't even know what the expected result is.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've added the helper2 function also above and also edit all functions in more details for better understanding. I hope now It's quite helpful!